# How to set text to change colour on IF ELSE results in a Thingsboard widget with javascript?

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

I have a ThingsBoard table widget displaying Node Status as 0 or 1. Where 0 = OK, 1 = ALARM.

I have already created nodeStatus to return strings of 0 = OK, 1 = ALARM.

[image: Sensor A Status]

The following is my current code in the 'Advanced Data Key Tab - Use cell content function':

```
var nodeStatus = entity['sensor.a'];

if (nodeStatus == '0')
{
    return "OK";
} else {
    return "ALARM";
}
```

I want to change the Returned String colour to the following:

OK = Green font

ALARM = Red font

How do I do this?

UPDATE: I have added extra code to the Cell Style function: f(value) as suggested by @lupz below.

[image: Data key configuration]

This is now making the entire column change to Red:

[image: Sensor A Status]

I have also tried enabling "Use data post-processing function" in the "Settings" Tab, with no change:

[image]

UPDATE:

I have removed the nodeStatus function from the "Cell Content Function" as per below comments:

[image]

After removal of the single quotes around the '0' next to if(value === 0), I have the same issue as above (the whole column is red).

[image]

Comment: Any news on this one? Please add the console output of this cell style function: `console.log(value, typeof (value)); return {};` Please add the console output of this cell content function: `console.log(value, typeof (value)); console.log(entity['sensor.a'], typeof (entity['sensor.a'])); return entity['sensor.a'];`

Comment: I am guessing you want me to do something with the Chrome Inspect tool (while selecting the Table)?

I have tried adding both the above statements but get errors in the syntax of those statements:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement" on both.

Comment: I'd like to get insights on the sensor data. The scripts will generate output that you can see in the log-console of your browsers development tools. Please paste "console.log('style value', value, typeof (value)); return {};" (without the double quotes) into the cell style function field. Please paste "console.log('content value', value, typeof (value)); console.log('content entity', entity['sensor.a'], typeof (entity['sensor.a'])); return entity['sensor.a'];" (without the double quotes) into the cell content function field. Please add the console output to you question.

Comment: Hi @lupz, i'd really like to answer you however I have been trying to get the Console output to work but I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement"

I am using the latest Chrome, right clicking the Sensor.A "ALARM" element in the Widget, and pasting the above into the Console area and hitting Enter. I am unsure where the Console area is in Chrome that will allow me to specifically select the "Cell Style Function" or the "Cell Content Function" Fields.

Comment: I guess we are not talking about the same things here. _In Thingsboard_ you can create dashboards with widgets. You can setup datasources for each widget by configuring data keys. In the advanced settings of each data key you can define a `cell style` and a `cell content` function. You can even see the textareas for those functions in your screenshots :) Please copy and paste the code from my previous comment into those textareas. The [console of your browser](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console) will show the output of the scripts when you access the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

There should be another script-input called `Cell style function: f(value)` right there in the advanced data key settings of the table widget. It can be used to set the CSS-styles for a cell based on its value:

```
/* Assuming value is your nodeStatus */

if (value === '0') {
    return {
        color: 'green'
    };
} else {
    return {
        color: 'red'
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have added this code to the Advanced tab in the "Cell style function: f(value)" section, however now I see all items in the column turn red. I am now able to add screenshots, so see my edited post above for extra clarification.

Comment: It is beacause the value is never `=== '0'`. hm... you use the `entity['sensor.a']` to get the nodeStatus and ignore the datakey value. What is the datakey? Can you add a datakey to access the `sensor.a` values directly?

Comment: In your screens I saw that it already is `sensor.a` datakey. You should be able to use the `value`-parameter of the cell content function directly (no need for `entity['sensor.a']`). The reason for this not working in the cell style function seems to be that your value is not a string but a number. You compare the sensor value to the string `'0'` and in Javascript `0 == '0'` is true due to automatic type conversions, whereas `0 === '0'` is false. You should be able to get it working by removing the single quotes `if (value === 0) { ... }`. Let me know if its working and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I have used entity['sensor.a'] instead of sensor.a directly as the datakey as it does not work properly with decimal places in the string name for a datakey.


I have removed the nodeStatus function to avoid confusion and added a screenshot above.


I have also tried removing the commas around the 0 next to value in the "Cell Style Function" and this did not work.

Comment: The problems seem to be that "sensor.a" is not properly recognized. By doing "Console.log(value)" I can see "undefined", whereby doing "Console.log(entity['sensor.a'])" I see the value... this seems to be a Bug on the Entities Table visualisation. Map works fine. To make things worst, the "entity" object is only available at "cell content function" but not at "cell style function".

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value == 'false') {
    return{background:'#0394fc'};
}
```